# How do I implement cascade deletes in the new version of Starcounter?

Tags: starcounter, database, nosql

In the new version I make persistent classes by using the [Database] attribute, I get that. How do I implement cascade deletes since Entity class, with the OnDelete() method, has been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just implement the IEntity interface on the class (or any parent class) you wish to implement the cascade delete on. IEntity has an OnDelete() method that will be called similar to how it worked before!

If you like you can easily do your own Entity class that implements IEntity and has the Database attribute set. Derive all your classes from this new class and your "old" code will work as in earier versions.